# $\int_{\Omega} D^{m} (|u|^{p-2}u) D^{m} u' dx\leq \|D^{m} u\|_{2}^{p-1}. \| D^{m} u'\|_{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

I am very confused about the following inequality which is written during of a proof in a paper. I don't know how it is obtained:
$$
\int_{\Omega} D^{m} (|u|^{p-2}u) D^{m} u' dx\leq  \|D^{m} u\|_{2}^{p-1}. \| D^{m} u'\|_{2}
$$
and in special case ($m=2$) 
$$
\int_{\Omega}\Delta (|u|^{p-2}u)\Delta u' dx\leq  \|\Delta u\|_{2}^{p-1}. \| \Delta u'\|_{2}.
$$
Note that $u\in H_{0}^{m}(\Omega)$. (Above inequality has been used in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X14002831, the inequalities (4.25) and (4.26)). How it can be true ? Thanks a lot for your guidance.